# Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. If $x<y$ then $0<1/y<1/x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I came across a proof in my textbook and was wondering how to solve it:

> *Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. If $x<y$ then $0<1/y<1/x$.*

Comment: I guess you believe $1/y$ and $1/z$ are positive... so the part you're stuck at is $1/y<1/x$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to some extent one could argue that there is nothing to show since this is obvious. Still, for a formal proof:

Multiply both sides of $x<y$ by $y^{-1}$ (NB: this is a positive number) to obtain $y^{-1}x<1$, then multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$ to obtain $y^{-1}<x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by inverting the inequality we get:

$x\lt y\Rightarrow \frac{1}{y}\lt\frac{1}{x}$, since $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\gt0}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{x}\gt 0$, if we combine everything we have:

$0\lt\frac{1}{y}\lt\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y>0$, then also $\frac1x,\frac1y>0$ and $\frac1{xy}>0$. Assuming you know multiplying by a positive number preverves inequality it's true that
$$x<y\Longrightarrow\frac1{xy}x<\frac1{xy}y\Longrightarrow\frac1y<\frac1x$$